# how to batch with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator? Do i needto modify generator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the `batch(8)` function, it modifies the shape and adds batch dimension, but only getting one image per batch. Below is my code:-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import random

folder_path = "./real/"
files = os.listdir(folder_path)

def get_image():
    index = random.randint(0,len(files)-1)
    img = cv2.imread(folder_path+files[index])
    img = cv2.resize(img,(128,128))
    img = img/255.
    #More complex transformation
    yield img

dset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_image,(tf.float32)).batch(8)

for img in dset:
    print(img.shape)
    break
```

The output still is (1, 128, 128, 3) even after using batch(8). Do I need to modify the generator to manually crate the batch? Also, how can it be wrapped in the generator in tensorflow so that it runs faster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its because your yield only takes a single image which you should yield in a loop, here's an example

```py
def get_image():
   for file in files:
      img = cv2.imread(folder_path + file)
      img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
      img = img / 255.

      yield img # Your supposed to yield in a loop

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_image, output_shapes=(128, 128), output_types=(tf.float32))

next(iter(dataset.batch(8))).shape

# TensorShape([8, 128, 128])
```

Comment: it is working, thanks. How many iteration the for loop iterate to generate a single batch of 8? my files list is very long..Is this approach optimised enough? sorry I am not python 100% guy.

Comment: You can use it as it is just set yiur dataset to a batch of 8 that would work

Comment: Hi @EdwinCheong
This is working, but in case of very large dataset with images, seems like get_image() is running over the big dataset at once, before diving into batches and passing fro training. Then wouldn't RAM be full with all those prepared data?